# Istio outlier detection not working as expected

Tags: istio, circuit-breaker

I am testing out Istio's circuit breaking capabilities. I am able to circuit break based on the http connections but when I tried to test based on outlierDetection it does not work.

I have made a simple DestinationRule

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: my-service-circuit-breaker
  namespace: test
spec:
  host: my-service.test.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    outlierDetection:
      consecutiveGatewayErrors: 1
      consecutive5xxErrors: 1
      interval: 1m
      baseEjectionTime: 1m
      maxEjectionPercent: 100
```

My service has a POST request with a URL param and a JSON body. The URL param is the status code to return to the caller and JSON body is to tell the service to sleep for the x number of seconds.

My service has a URI like: /test/<status_code>. (When I want to test I can send /test/503 or /test/200 so it returns the response I want.

```
// JSON Body
{
    "duration": 1
}
```

I have checked the istioctl proxy-config cluster command and the outlier detection is configured for the service

```
        "outlierDetection": {
            "consecutive5xx": 1,
            "interval": "60s",
            "baseEjectionTime": "60s",
            "maxEjectionPercent": 100,
            "enforcingConsecutive5xx": 100,
            "enforcingSuccessRate": 0,
            "consecutiveGatewayFailure": 1,
            "enforcingConsecutiveGatewayFailure": 100
        },
```

When I try to trip the circuit breaker by sending a POST request to the service /test/503. Subsequent calls with /test/200 still hit the service and return a 200 response. I am sending the calls locally from my PC, using fortio for load testing. I have tried using POSTMAN and exec into a pod within the same cluster to run curls to try to trip the endpoint but it still does not trip the circuit breaker.

I am running the service on 1 pod. (I have tried running 2 pods and specifically sending a 503 request to 1 pod and calling the service, however it doesn't seem like the pod that returned the 503 response was ejected from the load balancing pool as it still processed the subsequent request)

Istio version is 1.6.14

Answer (score 1):

Alright so the mistake was because I was calling the service locally using my computer. It needs to be called inside a pod with an istio-proxy as well. Not too sure why circuit breaking based on max connections is based on the destination proxy but for outlier detection is based on the caller's proxy. In essence, there isn't anything wrong with the DestinationRule just that I called it wrongly.

Comment: So cant we hit the service from outside and it is to be called from inside ? and how is it to be called?